# Problems with POSIXct in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am really struggling to understant `POSIXct` within `ggplot`. I would like to compute an histogram of my data which tells me in which hours during the night I have more records within my dataset.

I understand if I have to convert something using `as.POSIXct` I need a column in my original dataset with *date* + *time* or at least *date*. **The point is I only have time (HH:MM:SS)**, and I am not interested at all in the date itself. When applying:

```
our_data$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(our_data$timestamp, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

I look at my tibble and it looks like:
[image]

So my time is in grey and the function invented a date (current date actually).

That is fine, but when I try to produce my histogram with:

```
our_data %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = timestamp)) + geom_histogram() + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"), labels = date_format("%H:%M:%S"), limits = c("21:00:00", "07:00:00"))
```

I get the lovely error:

```
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
```

This is an extract of my dataset (first time using dput, sorry if it's wrong):

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18496, 18496, 18497, 18497, 
18498, 18498, 18498, 18499, 18499, 18500, 18501, 18504, 18505, 
18505, 18506, 18506, 18506, 18506, 18506, 18507, 18507, 18507, 
18507, 18507, 18509), class = "Date"), timestamp = structure(c(1600716120, 
1600724820, 1600716780, 1600659420, 1600645860, 1600654560, 1600640940, 
1600720260, 1600721580, 1600719660, 1600652160, 1600722600, 1600654020, 
1600660920, 1600639980, 1600662900, 1600652460, 1600661100, 1600662600, 
1600719480, 1600720500, 1600639260, 1600650420, 1600721940, 1600716420
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), siteid = c(2925L, 
2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 
2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 
2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L, 2925L), speciesid = c(29L, 
29L, 185L, 29L, 182L, 29L, 35L, 29L, 24L, 24L, 185L, 29L, 185L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 144L, 29L, 29L, 431L, 431L, 365L, 29L
), speciesname = c("Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Common Sandpiper", 
"Grey Heron", "Green Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", "Greater Flamingo", 
"Grey Heron", "Night Heron", "Night Heron", "Common Sandpiper", 
"Grey Heron", "Common Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", 
"Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Dotterel", "Grey Heron", 
"Grey Heron", "Ortolan Bunting", "Ortolan Bunting", "Spotted Flycatcher", 
"Grey Heron"), nmb_individuals = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), remark = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), migtype = c("M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), counttype = c("A", 
"", "A", "", "A", "", "", "A", "", "A", "A", "A", "A", "", "A", 
"", "", "", "", "A", "", "", "", "", "A"), yday = c(235L, 235L, 
236L, 236L, 237L, 237L, 237L, 238L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 243L, 244L, 
244L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 246L, 246L, 246L, 246L, 246L, 
248L), CodiEstacio = c("AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", 
"AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", 
"AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", "AM1", 
"AM1"), CodiEstacioCatalà = c("Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", 
"Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", 
"Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", 
"Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", 
"Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", 
"Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", 
"Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem", "Coll de Malrem")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Any help will be welcomed!

Comment: I believe you'll need to use `limits = c(as.POSIXct("2020-09-21 21:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-09-21 07:00:00"))`

Comment: Can you simply extract the hour from each `timestamp` (`lubridate::hour(timestamp)` would be one easy way to do it) and then just create a histogram on that new column? Or I haven't tried it, but `aes(x = hour(timestamp))` might work.

Comment: TheSciGuy what you suggest with no success. I get the error `Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument`

Comment: Thank Adam also for your help! I tried both approaches with no success in any. I think its because ggplot. The error is: `Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
`

Comment: Can you upload your dataframe, or a slice of it? Without a reproducible example it's hard to effectively help.

Comment: The error you get might be about the function `date_format()`, It seems like lacking some parts. I checked the function online you are using the library called `scales`, right?

Comment: I added a reproducible example, ope it works. And Abdurrahman yes, it is `scales` library! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got the way!

```
justtime <- function(x, split=12) {
  h <- as.numeric(strftime(x, "%H"))
  y <- as.POSIXct(paste(ifelse(h<split, "2015-01-02","2015-01-01"),strftime(x, "%H:%M:%S")))
}

data.frame(time=justtime(our_data$horacompleta)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=3600) + 
  ylab("nº observacions") + xlab("Hora") +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"), labels = date_format("%H:%M"),
                   limits = c(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 18:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-01-02 09:00:00")))
```

Producing:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you are looking for? I just extracted out the hour and plotted that. Can do some more formatting from here.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

our_data %>% 
  mutate(timestamp_h = hour(timestamp)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = timestamp_h)) + geom_histogram(bins = 24) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:12 * 2, limits = c(7, 21))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Adam! Though it is a simplification [`hour()`] it works for me! Despite this it's now working properly but because I don't fully understand your code i can't fix it. The thing to fix is that all my data is during the night, though in your graph they appear mainly during the evening. So, in `geom_histogram(bins = 24)` why 24, which is the unit of 24 here? Also if I set the limits let's say `limits = c(19, 06))` I get an empty graph. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are 24 hours in a day, that is why I tell the histogram to have 24 bins. Each bin (bar) represents an hour. Though that doesn't look like I did it correctly based on the widths in the graph. Odd. This approach treats hours as a number, not as a time unit. So when you set limits from 19 to 6, it does not know hours are circular. That is why that code fails. If you want to portray it that way as time, you will need to do something else. As you said, this is a simplification of the problem that generally works if you are willing to compromise a bit on the end visualization.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your answers!

Comment: Feel free to leave the question open. You might get an answer that more directly does what you want.